# passing a condition as a python parameter

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda, parameter-passing

I have a method, foo, that I run as a thread. I would like to pass a condition as a parameter. foo takes alot of steps. after each step I would like foo to return if the unique condition is met.

```
def foo(self, condition, other_args):
    self.do_stuff(other_args)
    if condition:
        return
    self.do_other_stuff(other_args)
    if condition:
        return
```

etc..

example conditionals I will be using are (self.attribute == value) OR (self.dif_attribute == dif_value)

ive been trying to create a lambda function

`condition = lambda value: value == self.attribute` and `conditional_2 = lambda value == self.dif_attribute`

So to add more information I am calling foo like so:

```
        thread = threading.Thread(target=self.foo,
                                  kwargs={"condition": condition,
                                          "other_args": self.bar})

        thread.start()
        thread.join()
```

but I am not sure how to pass the value in and cant seem to get it to work. Are lambdas the best way to do this? or should is there a simpler answer that i am not seeing.

so to clarify I am trying to pass a condtional (self.attribute == 'string') into  a method as a paramter. so that it can be used in the method like :

`if condition:`

***using python3.6 not sure if that matters***

Comment: Passing a `lambda` will work fine, as would passing a full, named function. Please elaborate on what you mean by "cant seem to get it to work".

Comment: How are you calling `foo`?

Comment: those `lambda`s don't work, presumably, because `self` is undefined,  you could pass in `self` as an argument though

Comment: Where do you get `value` from?

Comment: @kinshukdua value is a string that I am trying to verify. so I want to check that an attribute is set to a specific string value.

Comment: @L.Grozinger self is defined i left it out but this is within a class

Comment: @12944qwerty i edited the post

Comment: @Carcigenicate I dont understand how to create or call the lambda. 

if condition:

where condition can equal things like (self.bar == 'value') and other similar comparisons between an attribute and a string

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do so, you can pass a function that behave like a condition:

```
def con_func(x):
    if x > 10:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

now when you pass the function to another function it can behave like a condition:

```
def check(con = None, x = 0):
    if callable(con):
        is_true = con(x)
        if(is_true):
            print("ok")
        else:
            print("not ok")
```

now you can use it like:

```
check(con_func, 10)
```

and the output will be:

```
not ok
```

Comment: This is a good solution. but isnt super clean solution for me because i have many different conditionals that may need to be used so I would have to create individual methods for each one. this is why i am trying to use lambda so I can declare them as needed.

Answer (score 0):

What you really need is:

```
if condition(self):
```

because the condition needs to know about the object.

So, define your lambda to take an object instance as its parameter:

```
value = 5

condition = lambda instance: instance.attribute == value
```